# How to create a NFS root for Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, nfs, pxe

I am trying to set up several mini-PCs that all boot Ubuntu from unique NFS images mounted via PXE. The systems have no local storage or configuration and everything must come from network.

I have succeeded in PXE booting the live CD by hosting the contents of the Live CD on a nfs share. I unzipped the entire live cd ISO into a folder shared on NFS. The PXE environment will load the first level kernel/initrd from the Live CD over TFTP, then launch this along with some bootargs on the kernel command line. These bootargs tell the first level kernel to mount a nfs share as '/' and launch the real/full kernel from that. All well and good when '/' is the contents of the Ubuntu live CD. It boots up beautifully.

The next step I want to take is to swap the Live CD for a real, installed image of Ubuntu. I thought this would be as simple as swapping out the contents of the live CD for the contents of root from an installation, but this did not work. I crash into the buildroot console. Things seem to go haywire just after mounting nfs. Lots of errors related to cannot find xyz, none of which are the kernel or initrd from nfs root. I believe I have done something wrong when copying my root to NFS. I must be missing something. This NFS root is somehow invalid. Rather than rathole into exactly why this NFS root isn't working, let me rewind and ask a more high level question:

**How do I make a NFS root for Ubuntu?**

Do I copy folders from some system that already has Ubuntu installed? All folders or only some? Assuming all systems are either kvm64 or AMD64, are there any architectural issues with copying OS's? Have I missed some way to run the installer and somehow target NFS as the install 'disk'?

Answer (score 1):

I made two mistakes. The solution revolves around installing Ubuntu on a template machine and then copping the entire root partition from this machine to the NFS share.

Do not do the copy from the machine when it is running. Use a live CD or other separate bootable environment to copy the root partition.

Use `cp -a`. The a is important because it preserves all of the file permissions, including the SUID bits that allows key executable to run as root.